# How to prove the words in a regular language that start with abc constitute a regular language

Tags: regular-languages

Let $L$ be a regular language with alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$.

Prove that the following language is regular:

$\{w | w \in L \text{ and } w \text{ starts with } abc \}$.

I wonder what proof strategy I can use to prove this.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 2):

Use closure properties of regular languages.

Comment: $\{w | w \in L \text{ and } w \text{ starts with } abc \} = L \cap abc(a|b|c)^*$.  And regular languages are closed under intersection. Am I right?

Comment: Right, that's the simplest proof.